# How could I resize (not exactly strait scaling) dojo vectors?

Tags: javascript, vector, svg, dojo

I'm making a scheduling application with blocks for the.. schedule blocks. They're separated by 1px Rectangles. For the most part I can simply use transformations to scale the grid, but I obviously want these 1px separators to stay the same width.

Perhaps this is more of an opinion question and thus against the rules, but currently the only way I can think of doing it is keeping my lines in a separate array and then move/scaling them as needed by recalculating the new dimensions on a resize event, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this that I'm not aware of being new to dojo. If this is an acceptable method of doing it to though please say so as I don't want to get stuck into an anti-pattern from the start. Is there a more appropriate way to represent the blocklines than simply drawing them pragmatically w/vectors perhaps too?

edit: Was asked for a code sample. I could post my code, but it doesn't really matter, a simpler example would be something such as this:

```
var rect = surface.createRect({ x: 100, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100 })
.setFill("yellow");
```

Given the above how would I do something like changing the width to 300, or moving the object's position? I've tried modifying the underlying shape, in this case rect.shape, but it doesn't seem to apply the changes, not surprisingly.

That would be convenient if I could modify that, but I cannot find a way to apply those changes once done. Just taking a guess I tried running rect._applyTransform(), but that didn't work either, and I saw nothing else inspecting the dom that might be of use to me, nor could I find anything in the documentation short of percentage based scaling, which I could *make* work, but it would be rather inconvenient and I still cannot figure out how to simply move the object/change it's position.

edit2: **Found the answer, see below.**

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, I'm looking for the setShape method. This lets you set any of the shape properties directly, positional coordinates, height, width, and radius in the case of a rectangle. As best I can tell if you want to move it using relative positioning instead of absolute you just have to add (or subtract) from it's current position which can be gotten from the obj.shape properties, pretty simple.

So for example to move rect 50px to the right and make it 20px taller you'd do:

```
rect.setShape({height: rect.height + 20, x: rect.shape.x + 50});
```

Also if it's help to anyone to remove a shape simply call the removeShape method, took me a minute to find it out; I don't like the way dojo's reference is setup and have so far had better luck browsing the dom using firebug for better or worse.